# What is the best List implementation for Large lists in java

Tags: java, list, apache-commons, shuffle

I have to create a large list of n elements (could be up to 100,000). each element in the list is an integer equivalent to the index of the list. After this I have to call Collections.shuffle on this list. My question is, which list implementation (either java collections or apache collections) should be used. My gut feeling is ArrayList can well be used here. 
All thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks!

Thanks for the inputs. I think I am sticking to the ArrayList. I am currently using the ArrayList constructor with the initialCapacity param and I pass the size of the list. So if the original list is 100000, I create this new list with new ArrayList(100000); Hence I think I don't have the create an array and do an asList since there won't be any resizing. Also, most of the apache collections Lists like GrowthList & LazyList do not implement RandomAccess. This for sure would slow down the shuffle (as per javadocs). FastArrayList does implement RandomAccess but apache has a note for this class saying "This class is not cross-platform. Using it may cause unexpected failures on some architectures".

Comment: Could you elaborateon the goal that you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you do with the List after adding and shuffling? Do you add/ delete elements at the middle? Do you add/delete elements at the ends? Do you access elements at the middle in an arbitrary order, or do you do a single pass from one end to the other? It is really hard to decide without knowing what it is that you are going to do with it. If all you want to do is add numbers serially and shuffle, I would say ArrayList is the answer.

Comment: 100000 is not that large these days.  Doing it in the most naive way with an array list takes less than 100ms on my machine (single core of Intel Core2 T5600 @ 1.83GHz).

Answer (score 13):

ArrayList most probably has the least overhead per list element, so should be the best choice. It might be a worse choice if you frequently need to delete items in the middle of the list.

Comment: Actually, int[] would have less overhead, what to choose depends on what he needs it for.

Comment: @rsp: int[] doesn't implement List - you'd need a wrapper round it.

Comment: Only if you insist in using Collections.Shuffle :-) but point taken.

Answer (score 6):

Quoted from the Collections.shuffle javadoc:

> This method runs in linear time. If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list. This avoids the quadratic behavior that would result from shuffling a "sequential access" list in place.

So if you have no other needs i would go with ArrayList which implements RandomAccess.

Answer (score 5):

Making an `Integer` array and then wrapping it with [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) gives you even less overhead than a regular `ArrayList`.

```
List<Integer> makeList(int size){
    if (size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) arr[i] = i;
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    Collection.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}
```

You save one entire `int` worth of space (... which admittedly is absolutely nothing in this context), but it does perform fewer range checks than the "real" `ArrayList`, so accessing will be slightly faster. Probably nothing you'll notice, though :)

Comment: Presumably when you use a `List`, you don't allocate an array yourself. You just, well, use a `List`.

Comment: Uhm, that depends on how you do it, which happens to be the essence of this question - how to create a large list with little overhead.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<T>` would probably be fine, yes - but what criteria are you using for "best" anyway? And just how good does it have to be anyway? What are your trade-offs between complexity and "goodness" in whatever those criteria are?

Answer (score 2):

[Javolution](http://javolution.org/apidocs/index.html) claims to have the fastest List implementation in java. But I couldn't find any shuffle implementation in this library so you will have to do it by hand.

Comment: the Javolution API docs link has changed. It is now at http://javolution.org/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library has some really nice primitive handling, including an [Ints.asList()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) method returning a list that may be shuffled.

The Guava project is still at a preliminary stage of deployment, though the code has been carefully reviewed and heavily used at Google. You'll need to retrieve the code from [SVN](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/checkout) and build the com.google.common.primitive classes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new List implementation called [GlueList](https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/GlueList) which is very fast than ArrayList and LinkedList.

**Disclaimer**: I've created the implementation.

Comment: It is customary to state that you are the author, if you are.

Answer (score 1):

This is about your update to your question concerning `FastArrayList`.

> `FastArrayList` does implement `RandomAccess` but apache has a note for this class saying "This class is not cross-platform. Using it may cause unexpected failures on some architectures".

The `FastArrayList` class ([javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/FastArrayList.html)) is a concurrent list class.  This is what the javadoc says:

> A customized implementation of java.util.ArrayList designed to operate
>   in a multithreaded environment where the large majority of method
>   calls are read-only, instead of structural changes. When operating in
>   "fast" mode, read calls are non-synchronized and write calls perform
>   the following steps:
>
> 1. Clone the existing collection
> 2. Perform the modification on the clone
> 3. Replace the existing collection with the (modified) clone
>
> [...]
>
> **NOTE**: If you are creating and accessing an ArrayList only within a
>   single thread, you should use java.util.ArrayList directly (with no
>   synchronization), for maximum performance.
>
> **NOTE**: This class is not cross-platform [*due to issues with
>   fast mode and multiple threads*]

Now your use-case (as described) is single-threaded.  So:

- The "cross-platform" issue is not relevant because it only affects multi-threaded use-cases.
- The first "NOTE" says (clearly) that for a single-threaded application you are better off using an `ArrayList`.

In short, the "fast" in `FastArrayList` is relative to (say) doing this:

```
  List<String> myConcurrentlList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

---

Back to your original question.  `ArrayList` is the simplest of the fast ways, and I doubt that any other `List` class will beat it.  However, the following **approach** *may* be faster.

```
  String[] array = new String[...];
  // populate array
  // shuffle array ... using same algorithm as Collections.shuffle
  for (int i = array.length; i > 1; i--)
      swap(array, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(i));
  }
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Why might that be faster?  Because swap operations on an array will be faster than on an `ArrayList`.

Will it be faster overall?  Hard to say.  It depends on:

- whether you creating / populating the array like that is / isn't extra work
- whether the performance of list operations on an `asList` wrapper compared to an `ArrayList` ... and what operations you perform, etc.

---

My advice would be to beware of "premature optimization".

Answer (score -1):

ArrayList will be the best List for this. As the array backing will be very efficent for swapping elements used in shuffle.

But if you are really chacing performance you may wish to consider using an int[] or a custom list based in int[] as with all the List and List standard implementations you will be boxing and unboxing ints to Integers.

This will not be an issue on the suffle as this will just be reordering pointers but you will be creating 100,000 objects when you may not need to. Assuming you know the size of your list before creation you can quite easily create a new List class that wraps a primitive array. If used as a java.util.List you will still need to box the return from any get method.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use memory mapped file based list implementation . In such implementation the list is not fully present in memory but only a section of the huge list will be active in memory.
If you are reaching heap space limitation (mostly in 32 bit jvm) you may be needing to make the list push off data seamlessly using a memory mapped file which will be faster than normal file I/O.
One such implementation is described in this [google code](http://code.google.com/p/biglist-javalist/wiki/BigList) and explained in this [link](http://simple4java.com/2013/04/25/big-collection-in-java-biglist/).